# How to set current date as git commit message

Tags: git, bash

How to set current date as git commit message?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to set the date as the commit message? After all, the commit already stores the date when it was committed.

Comment: I totally agree with Amber. This information is already stored, so you might as well make all your commit messages say "a". It's shorter and easier, and stores just as much information.

Comment: for what it's worth, this question ended up helping me because i wanted to include the date in a git alias (`git today` = `git checkout -b w-${1-``date +\"%Y-%m-%d\"``}`) _(double backticks should be single, boo markdown)_

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
git commit -m "`date`" filename
```

Comment: and if you want to [format the date](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/): ``date +\"%Y-%m-%d\"`` _(in Windows, ymmv)_

Comment: @KushalJayswal it does work with Git Bash on Windows 10. Just make sure you put the quotes properly:
`git commit -m "\`date +\"%Y-%m-%d\"\`"`

Answer (score 22):

```sh
git commit -m "`date`" # Wed Aug 28 10:22:06 CST 2019
git commit -m "`date +'%Y-%m-%d'`" # 2019-08-28
git commit -m "Updated: `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`" # Updated: 2019-08-28 10:22:06
```

```
current="`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`"
msg="Updated: $current"
git commit -m "$msg" # Updated: 2019-08-28 10:22:06
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, this command works:

```
git commit -m "$(Get-Date)"
```